# How best to manage Google API credentials in an AWS Lambda function and serverless framework?

Tags: lambda, google-api, serverless-framework

I'm porting a python flask app onto Lambda and have a google service account json file which is used by the app.

I'm using [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) to manage the project deployment.

The google service account json file is normally loaded as a file from the hard drive into the `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]`.  I understand that if you wish to load it from an escaped string stored in something like AWS property store an OAuth provider dependency is also needed to process the credentials and I'd rather avoid that.

So I'm currently thinking of storing the google service account json file in the lambda function deployment.

This makes me a bit uncomfortable, but I can't think of another way to do it.

I also don't want to commit the google service account json file to source control either of course.

Two questions please:

1. Does serverless framework have a way to copy a file from a location outside the project structure and include it in the project structure on deployment so that I can check my project structure into source control without the json file?
2. Is there a better approach for dealing with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you using but in python the Credentials class says

> Service account credentials

```
Usually, you'll create these credentials with one of the helper
constructors. To create credentials using a Google service account
private key JSON file::

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'service-account.json')

Or if you already have the service account file loaded::

    service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        service_account_info)
```

So instead of loading the file you can just save whatever is in the json file in your secrets manager. Then you access the values in your lambda and authenticate using `from_service_account_info` instead of `from_service_account_file`

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            service_account_info)
```

`service_account_info` dictionary has to have the same fields as the original file